# Environment Variable for Process

Tags: python, environment-variables, subprocess

I need to start process within python script, so I use for this `subprocess.Popen()` and give environment variables through parameter `env` of `Popen` function, but my process doesn't see needed environment variables. 
How can I do it? 
Any help will be appreciated.

I'm running OS X 10.5.

Example:

```
env = os.environ
env["Foo"] = foo

cmd = "/usr/bin/sudo -H -u "+ self.getCurrentUserName() + "-P" + +os.path.join(dir, app) + app_args

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, cwd=dir, env=env)
```

Comment: For privacy reasons I'll ask you to post the code in question instead of just reading it from your mind.

Comment: Did you add all of the needed variables to the environment

Comment: avoid modifying `os.environ` inplace, pass a copy to `Popen(cmd, env=dict(os.environ, Foo=foo), ...)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `sudo` resets the environment of the program it runs for security reasons.  If you want to avoid that, you need to pass in the `-E` flag to `sudo`, and either the command you're running has to have the `SETENV` tag or the `setenv` option has to be set in the `sudoers` file.  See the [`sudo` man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html) and the [`sudoers` man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging or printing out all of the available environment variables from within the program that you're calling, maybe it's there but different.  In Windows, for example, environment variables end up being all upper-case.